# Data binding with LiveData<Drawable> nullifies value on BindingAdapter?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm having a problem updating `drawableLeft` of `TextView` using data binding.

**My live data:**

```
val iconLiveData = MutableLiveData<Drawable>()
```

**My binding adapter:**

```
@BindingAdapter("drawableLeft")
fun TextView.setDrawableLeft(drawable: Drawable?) {
    Timber.d("Setting drawable from adapter: $drawable")
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
}
```

**TextView in layout:**

```
<TextView
    ...removed all other params for simplicity
    drawableLeft="@{viewModel.iconLiveData}"/>
```

**Code that changes drawable:**

```
val drawable = repository.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_google_fit)
                Timber.d("Setting drawable: $drawable")
                iconLiveData.value = drawable
```

**Here is what happens when I execute value change:**

```
2019-11-04 14:49:51.296 23568-23568 D/LOG: Setting drawable: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable@347943e
2019-11-04 14:49:51.298 23568-23568 D/LOG: Setting drawable from adapter: null
```

`Drawable` goes into to `LiveData`, but when it goes out inside `BindingAdapter`, it's null. Looks like `Drawable` can't be passed via `LiveData`, but I can't find any confirmation for that.

For **reasons** I cannot use resource instead of Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the time I implemented livedata in databinding, I've found there was a lot of type issues, which would trigger the binding adapter with null value.

First, try to inject the drawable in your databinding without livedata. E.g : in your activity/fragment get the drawable value from your livedata and put it in your databinding. See if the drawable is null or not.
If the drawable is not null, then there's a lot of chances the databinding lib messes with the type of drawableLeft in the bindingadapter.

You can also try to read the generated databinding code to understand what's going on under the hood and where the use of livedata in databinding fails.

The name of the databinding property "drawableLeft" may cause errors since it's a string used in the framework out of the databinding lib.

I'd love to hear back from your issue to know how you went over this.